# Change the button icon from bootstrap is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've the following button and I want to add it bootstrap icon from the following link
(the + icon in the begining)and currelntly its not working ,what Im missing here ?

http://getbootstrap.com/components/

This is the button

```
<div style="float:right; text-align:right;">
    <p>
        <input type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"  value="Add Row" onclick="addRow()" id="add-row" />
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608873/how-to-include-glyphicons-in-bootstrap-3 - This is one great answer, you might find your answer there as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrap button text is inserted via `value` field which cannot hold an icon, the easiest way to achieve what you are trying to do is to replicate the button using the anchor tag:

```
<a href="#" onclick="addRow()" id="add-row" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Row </a>
```

Giving an anchor class `btn btn-default` makes it look exactly like a button, and the text can be appended with the icon.

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/gbGKLmIhWH)**

Comment: Thanks voted up!last question how should I change the text color to black and the icon to green?

Comment: @shopiaT Simply target the `i` and its class -> `i.glyphicon{ color: green; }`. [Demo here](http://www.bootply.com/TXMjPIzYgC)

Comment: Thanks ,how should I change the text to black ,Ive tried with     .add-row {
        color: black;
    } which is not working ,any idea?

Comment: @shopiaT `.` is used for classes, `add-row` is an `id` there so you would use `#add-row{}`

Comment: Using the `<button>` tag would seem to make more sense.

Comment: @cvrebert Oh yes, that seems like a better approach. Weirdly it didn't cross my mind.