# How to add fonts to cakephp

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, glyphicons

I'm trying to add bootstrap to a cakephp site.  I added bootstrap js/css's in default.ctp and I want to use some glyphicons in buttons, but the request for the fonts (.ttf) fails (404). I have them in /app/webroot/fonts.

Apparently cake is interpreting that I want to use a controller named fonts, when I do the request from the address bar I get:

Missing Controller
Error: FontsController could not be found.

Error: Create the class FontsController below in file: app\Controller\FontsController.php

How do I bypass this so the font file is downloaded?

This is what I've done:
1) Add bootstrap to default.ctp

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
```

2) Create a button with a glyphicon in a index.ctp:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" aria-label="Left Align">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>Add
</button>
```

Comment: Where is the code u tried?

Comment: Think this is about Cake not finding the files. Is your fonts directory as the same level as your css and js directories - see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608873/how-to-include-glyphicons-in-bootstrap-3 . Might be worth trying the HtmlHelper ($this->Html->script() and $this->Html->css() to write those <link> and <script> tags for you: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html

Comment: Yes, the fonts directory is at the same level as css/js.  I'm going to try using the helper, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try to load bootstrap this way :

```
echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap');
echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap');
```